# Asymmetric data analyses

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, count-data

I have a data set containing bacterial count values before treatment and after treatment. These data look asymmetric. Please advise me for a suitable statistical test to find if the introduction of the new drug significantly reduced the bacterial count. I was thinking of the Wilcoxon signed-rank test. If you think that's the correct one, on what basis should I define hypothetical median value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data seems to be paired and is asymmetric (thus, non-normal), I agree that the Wilcoxon test is a good choice.

As for the descriptive statistics, I suggest that you compute the quartiles before treatment and the quartiles after treatment. It may also be interesting to create a new variable $\Delta = a - b$, i.e., the difference between the bacterial count $a$ after the treatment and the bacterial count $b$ before the treatment (negative values of $\Delta$ indicate a decrease in bacterial count). Then, you can take a look at the quartiles of $\Delta$ (in general, they may not be equal to each quartile of $a$ - the same quartile of $b$).

**Edit:** The Wilcoxon test will compare the bacterial count before treatment $b$ with the bacterial count after the treatment $a$. Therefore, you will get one $p$ value for each experiment.

**Edit2:** A $p$ value below the usual cut-off of 0.05 means that you can reject the null hypothesis that the distributions of the bacterial count before the treatment $b$ and after the treatment $a$ are the same, which means that the distributions are significantly different. Remember that you can take a look at the median of each group and/or at the median of $\Delta$ to help you understand in which direction are the differences.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. I did the analyses but I got p values less than 0.0001 for all the control and tests. Is this real or anything is wrong with my settings? The analyses were done at alpha=0.05 and hypothetical median =0.

Comment: @OmShree: I'll edit my answer a bit to clarify that you should do one Wilcoxon test to compare $a$ with $b$. Hence, you will have only one $p$ value. By the way, if my answer ends up solving your problem, you're welcome to accept it. :)

Comment: Hi @Ertxiem, I did do one Wilcoxon test to compare a with b. The data i uploaded represents experiment number 1. I have 27 such experiments and all them are showing p<0.0001. Thank you

Comment: @OmShree: there is nothing wrong with your data. A low $p$ value means that are significant differences between $a$ and $b$. I've edited my answer with more information.

Comment: Hi Errtxiem. Thank you for your clear response. I got a new problem. The number of controls in my study is 10 and the number of tests 17. Is it ok if I compare a-b between 10 controls and 17 tests or should I pick only 10 tests or is there any way to normalise? Thank you

Comment: That's indeed another question, @OmShree. To answer it I would need to understand what is happening to make the number of controls different from the number of cases. I'm thinking that perhaps instead of considering paired samples you should consider independent samples and use the [Mann-Whitney test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test).

Comment: Hi @Ertxiem. Actually we were planning for 17 control and 17 tests but since this test involved sampling from human individuals, we did not get more than 10 controls. But did not left behind 7 test subjects just to make 10 in each arm. The data set i added in my first question is for test subject 1. I have 17 similar data set for test and 10 for control.

Comment: From what you described, the individuals in the control group are independent (i.e., non related) to the individuals in the test group, so the Mann-Whitney test is appropriate.

Comment: One tailed seems appropriate to me since your alternative hypothesis is that the treatment is better than the control (thus, the null hypothesis is that the treatment is worse than or equal to the control).

Comment: I'm going to be a bit bold and ask you to please accept my answer (there is a green button next to the number) on the top left side of it. I think I worked for it! :)